# Scattering ${\cal M}$- and $S$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, definition, s-matrix-theory

I am reading QFT book, like Introduction to QFT by Peskin and Schroeder, I would like to know conceptually what is the difference between $S$-matrix and invariant matrix element ${\cal M}$ in scattering. When Ward-Takahashi identity is discussed, P&S states (under eq. (7.68) on page 242) that it reduced to Ward identity only when ${\cal M}$ is an $S$-matrix element, which means ${\cal M}$ can be equals to something else (not an $S$-matrix), so what will it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P&S write under eq. (7.64) on p. 238:

> To discuss this more general case we will let ${\cal M}$ denote a Fourier-transformed correlation function, in which the external momenta are not necessarily on-shell.